# Refactor Mvc 5 Identity on 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, refactoring, asp.net-identity, 3-tier

i'm trying to work with OWIN and new Asp.Net Mvc 5 Identity.
Now i would like to refactor the template created by visual studio 2013 into a 3 tier application with:

- Presentation Layer (Mvc)
- Logic
- Data

Usually i declare inside Logic layer the interfaces of repository (IRepository<'T'>) and in Data project the implementations of this interfaces with an abstract generic implementation and the specific implementations. 
My DbContext and Initalization of DbContext are in Data Layer.
My Data Layer have a reference to Logic Layer.

Now i'm trying to do the same with Identity classes:

I'm creating an ApplicationDbContext that inherit from IdentityDbContext inside a Data Layer and in Logic/Model i have the ApplicationUser (inherit from IdentityUser) but i don't know where to place ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager

This line of code

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

makes me doubt.

I Would like to manage my Users like other objects defined in Logic/Models.

This is what i have in Data Layer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Logic.Interfaces;


public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    protected ApplicationDbContext _context;

    protected AbstractRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public virtual T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(match);
    }

    public virtual ICollection<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Where(match).ToList();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}

public class ToDoRepository : AbstractRepository<Logic.Models.ToDo>
{
    public ToDoRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

And in Logic layer (Logic/Interfaces):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Logic.Interfaces
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
    {
         T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match);

         ICollection<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match);

         ICollection<T> GetAll();
    }
}
```

And Logic/Models

```
namespace Logic.Models
{
    public class ToDo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Managers are supposed to sit in middle of your UI and DAL. Managers decide on what resources the UI requests and gets those from DAL. So the best place to keep your User and Signin Managers is in the Logic layer.. Only problem I see is why does your Data layer references the Logic ? Ideally it should be other way round..

Comment: Thanks... usually my data layer need to reference logic layer because i have models defined in logic layer. So if i reference data in logic layer i will have circular refernce.

Comment: Its always better to keep your POCO classess in a separate assembly that way you can reference them in both layers.

Comment: Should i place in the new assemby ApplicationUser class ?